# How to new line when post string to wall Facebook?

Tags: ios4, facebook-graph-api

I code to post to wall Facebook as below:

```
- (void)publishStream{
NSLog(@"body %@",bodyMeaning);
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"SAOL Dictionary",@"message",
                               @"http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/", @"link",
                               @"http://bit.ly/riDGff", @"picture",
                               keyword, @"name",
                                @"Facebook caption example." , @"caption",
                                 facebookBody, @"description",
                               nil];

NSLog(@"%@",bodyMeaning);
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

}

When it appear in wall : **Facebook caption example**.
But i want to appear as: **Facebook

                         Caption

                         Example.**
(new lines format)
Any body know this please help me!.

Thanks all.

Comment: `@"Facebook\ncaption\nexample."` doesn't work?

Comment: Facebook not understand \n or some html tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert newline in "caption" attribute through Facebook Graph API wall post?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5674616/how-to-insert-newline-in-caption-attribute-through-facebook-graph-api-wall-post)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add

```
<center></center>
```

as the new line character

Comment: it new line but have long space as "          Facebook...".

Comment: Thanks. If use Facebook<center></center>Caption<center></center>Example then it worked.

Comment: Will this work for the description of the posted data? I am looking for a way to format the description to be more user-friendly, but it looks like html tags (`<p>`, `<br>`) are not working, neither is the `\n` character.